What would cause packets leaving an interface to have the source IP of a different NIC with Ubuntu 24?
Let's say I have a server with two NICs in it.
eno1: 192.168.1.100/24 
eno2: 169.254.2.1/16

Traffic in/out of NIC 1 has no problem. I can get SSH in, ping out, etc… No problem.
However after running a netplan generate && netplan apply on Ubuntu 24, or even running ifconfig eno2 169.254.2.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 up, when I run tcpdump -i eno2 i see the IP address from eno1 egressing out eno2, instead of the .2.1 address
Prior:
22:39:41.937488 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 169.254.2.1 > 169.254.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 27057, seq 1, length 64
22:39:41.938469 00:11:22:33:44:55 > aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 169.254.2.2 > 169.254.2.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27057, seq 1, length 64
22:39:42.937626 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 169.254.2.1 > 169.254.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 27057, seq 2, length 64
22:39:42.938563 00:11:22:33:44:55 > aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 169.254.2.2 > 169.254.2.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27057, seq 2, length 64
22:39:43.964645 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 169.254.2.1 > 169.254.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 27057, seq 3, length 64
22:39:43.965546 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 169.254.2.2 > 169.254.2.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27057, seq 3, length 64

After:
22:43:37.872518 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.100 > 169.254.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 29192, seq 1, length 64
22:43:38.908604 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.100 > 169.254.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 29192, seq 2, length 64
22:43:39.932634 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff > 00:11:22:33:44:55, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.100 > 169.254.2.2: ICMP echo request, id 29192, seq 3, length 64

There is a slight chance, that by doing an ifconfig down and ifconfig up that it might suddenly work again, but for the life of me I can't find the cause.   there is no router involved, this is purely eno2 talking to another device directly connected to it, and it's not something with the default route since I see the traffic egressing over eno2 and not eno1.
netplan status shows no 192.x address on the 2nd NIC, and when I hook 2 machines together, one with Ubuntu 24 and one with Ubuntu 20, the Ubuntu 20 machine has no problems pinging the Ubuntu 24 machine, but the Ubuntu 24 machine shows it's eno1 address on the outbound packets instead of the eno2 address.    both machines have UFW disabled, and iptables flushed.

Are those the actual addresses you used? Beware that the IPv4 link-local subnet (169.254.0.0/16) has special rules per IETF ZeroConf.

Can you show your whole routing table (ip -4 route and ip -4 rule) plus the kernel's routing decision (ip route get 169.254.2.2 and ip route get 169.254.2.2 fibmatch)?

Many things can cause this. Too many. Check your routing table, Netplan config, interface binding, and IP assignment. Check for any IP forwarding or NAT rules, reboot and interface initialization, check for kernel or driver issues, even though less likely. And for debugging test with static routes, and also cross-check with another machine.

The basic "cause" is that the IP address really belongs to the Linux host rather than a specific interface. This is related to the ARP flux problem in Linux. You have been fooled by Linux commands that seem like you're assigning the IP address to an interface. See answers to https://serverfault.com/questions/312221/can-a-single-network-card-have-2-ip-addresses
